# Downgrading Symfony2 from 2.4.1 to 2.3.9

Tags: php, symfony

I have started an application development on **Symfony2.4.1**. But later decided to go back to **Symfony2.3.9** as it has **long term support**. Is there any procedure to downgrade (Found no luck on Google), or I have to download 2.3.9 and push all my code there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have just managed to downgrade my Symfony 2.4.1 to 2.3.9.

### 1) Update composer.json

Remove the following lines:

```
"symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
"doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
"twig/extensions": "~1.0",
"symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
"symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
"symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
"sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
"sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
"sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
```

And add the following ones:

```
"symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
"doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
"twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
"symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
"symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
"symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
"sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
"sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
"sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
```

### 2) Update monolog config

Comment (with #) or remove the following lines in app/config/config_dev.yml:

```
console:
  type:   console
  bubble: false
```

And do the same in app/config/config_prod.yml:

```
console:
  type:   console
```

Those configuration options were not available in 2.3.*, so they cause errors if not removed.

### 3) Run composer

```
php composer.phar update
```

### 4) Clear the cache (the old way)

After updating composer, I couldn't clear the cache through `app/console` (it returned an exception).

Instead, I had to delete both `dev` and `prod` folders inside `app/cache/`.

### 5) Enjoy LTS!

Long term support is always good :)