# Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given when i install composer.phar

Tags: symfony, composer-php, bundle, vendor

I try to install an existing project,

when I try to execute : `php composer.phar install =>` I get this error,

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]   Warning:
>   trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
>
> Script
>   Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
>   handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception
>
> [RuntimeException]   An error occurred when executing the
>   ""cache:clear --no-warmup"" command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony2 Composer Install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338803/symfony2-composer-install)